# Custom action hook needed - on article load - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey there. I'm currently learning how to write plugins for wordpress platform and I already know the basics. However, I need to invoke some function when a single article page (single.php) loads. Basically, I want to take that post ID and use it in my algorithm. I can't find any pre-defined action hook in wordpress framework so I thought I could write my very own one, but I don't know what's the mechanism for it. I read several guides on internet but still have no clue how it works. Can someone help me with this? Code examples are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can start at the loop_start hook and check is_single() or whatever else you need to determine if you're being called from a singular page. I highly doubt you need to be creating new action hooks in the WordPress core for whatever you're doing.